# Paypal php sdk problen

Tags: php, paypal, sdk

Hey i have a problem with my php code. When i tried in on localhost it worked but when i upload it to my server it doesn't.

I think the problem is here.

```
$payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);

echo '10';

try {

echo " 10 ";

$payment->create($api);


echo '11';
```

And as you can see there is echo " 10 "; and echo " 11 "; and the last number shown is 10.

The error I get:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException' with message 'HEJ HEJGot Http response code 500 when accessing https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment.' in /var/www/jjracing.dk/public_html/Tipperen/PayPal-PHP-SDK/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Core/PayPalHttpConnection.php:159 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/jjracing.dk/public_html/Tipperen/PayPal-PHP-SDK/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Transport/PayPalRestCall.php(74): PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection->execute('{"intent":"sale...') #1 /var/www/jjracing.dk/public_html/Tipperen/PayPal-PHP-SDK/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Common/PayPalResourceModel.php(103): PayPal\Transport\PayPalRestCall->execute(Array, '/v1/payments/pa...', 'POST', '{"intent":"sale...', NULL) #2 /var/www/jjracing.dk/public_html/Tipperen/PayPal-PHP-SDK/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Api/Payment.php(303): PayPal\Common\PayPalResourceModel::executeCall('/v1/payments/pa...', 'POST', '{"intent":"sale...', NULL, Object(PayPal\Rest\ApiContext), NULL) #3 /var/www/jjracin in /var/www/jjracing.dk/public_html/Tipperen/PayPal-PHP-SDK/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Core/PayPalHttpConnection.php on line 159
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on your log file, at the end : http://pastebin.com/WsvDEJtq Line 457, You have null in your transaction object. You should be passing a transaction object in there.

You can checkout the logs on the same bin and you would see that the ones that were successful have transaction filled in properly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The payment is paypal and when i get home i can send you the log file if you want?

Comment: Log file would be extremely helpful.